# SQL - Make sure a column is unique over multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, unique, rows

I have a table in MySQL, which represents a user, that should be able to add up to three phone numbers to his account. So of course no phone number, that already exists should be able to be registered again. I made all three columns unique, but the problem is, that you can still enter as number 2 a number, that someone else entered as his first number. So I was wondering, if there is an SQL possibility to ensure, that one row is unique with other rows too or I need to solve this issue with querying, if there exists already a member with this number programmatically.

| MemberID | Main number | Number 2 | Number 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 456 | 789 |
| 2 | 456 | 123 | 567 |

So this example should be forbidden.

Comment: Normalise your schema. E.g.: member_id, number_attribute, number_value (although it seems odd that members could never share numbers)

Comment: As a palliative you may create according CHECK constraint, like `CHECK (!(x1=x2 OR x1=x3 OR x2=x3))`. But normalizing is preferred.

Comment: @Strawberry I think you comment is the best solution. You wanna post it as an answer? (And maybe explain it for people, that are not that experienced with databases. I understood you, but I also had a course about databases. :D)

Comment: Nope, but feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

So as Strawberry assumed the best solution is to normalize the table. Since every member as 1 to n numbers, the numbers should be an own entity.

The resulting solution would be to remove the number fields out of the member table and create a new table, which looks the following:

| Member_Id (Foreign Key) | Priority | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 234 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Then a unique constraint on the number column ensures, that no number is used by two members.

Comment: ... or even twice by the same user